# How to load any resource using Scala.js

Tags: html, scala, browser, scala.js

I'd like to read up a 30M file, and parse it using a custom logic from the browser, using Scala.js. How to do that?

Comment: I guess your "resources" file is accessible through some URL? In that case you use an AJAX request to retrieve it. In Scala.js, the easiest way to do that is through [org.scalajs.dom.ext.Ajax](https://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-dom/0.9.0/index.html#org.scalajs.dom.ext.Ajax$).

Comment: I just did that.